# Query for all fields

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver

I have a mongo collection that looks like this

```
db.SymbolMCIpPort.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f7bdaee23020650635ed3c"), "Provider" : "BROKER1", "Symbol" : "EURUSD", "MCIpPort" : { "IP" : "224.0.0.1", "PORT" : "12345" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59f7bdaee23020650635ed3d"), "Provider" : "BROKER1", "Symbol" : "EURJPY", "MCIpPort" : { "IP" : "224.0.0.1", "PORT" : "12346" } }
```

I am trying to query it to find all the fields that match EURUSD, like this:

```
// Create the query filter
auto filter = document{} << "Symbol" << "EURUSD"
                             << finalize;
// Create the find options with the projection
mongocxx::options::find opts{};
opts.projection(document{} << "_id" << "Provider" << "Symbol" << 1 << finalize);

// Execute find with options
auto cursor = coll.find(filter.view(), opts);
for (auto &&doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```

But it only gets me two fields, the `id` and `Symbol` [I am even confused why I don't also get the `Provider` field let alone the rest of the fields that match EURUSD.]

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "59f7bdaee23020650635ed3c" }, "Symbol" : "EURUSD" }
```

How do I modify the code to get all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it slightly differently with `find_one`:

```
auto filter = document{} << "Symbol" << rawSymbol
                                     << finalize;

bsoncxx::stdx::optional<bsoncxx::document::value> maybe_result = coll.find_one(filter.view());
if(maybe_result) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(*maybe_result) << "\n";
}
```